# Retrieving multipart form data from a mongodb gridfs database and displaying image in react native app

Tags: javascript, mongodb, react-native, multer, gridfs

Please I need help, I have been stuck on this problem for the past two weeks. I am uploading text data along with images using multer and gridfs to mongodb database and the upload works fine as the data is uploaded and stored in different chunks. However I am trying to accomplish two things:

1. Retrieve the data stored alongside the image
2. Get the image data and display it in my react native app

My database looks like this:

[image]
[image]

The data text data is in the post collection, while the image data is in the image_uploads.chunks and image_upload.files which are all uploaded via the same post route using multipart form data, multer and gridfs.

This is the server side get route where I am retrieving data from mongodb and serving the client side.

```js
/////////////////////////////Media Download Route//////////////////////
router.get('/post', async (req, res) => {
  gfs.files.find().toArray((err, files) => {
    // Check if files
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      res.send({ files: false });
    } else {
      files.map(file => {
        if (
          file.contentType === 'image/jpeg' ||
          file.contentType === 'image/png'
        ) {
          file.isImage = true;
        } else {
          file.isImage = false;
        }
      });
      res.send({ files: files});
    }
  });
});
```

Below is the client side code, that receives the data from the server.

```js
    const [photo, setPhoto] = useState(null)

    const getPost = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await dataApi.get('/post');
            const image = response.data.files[0].filename

            console.log(response.data)
            console.log('Image: ', image)
            console.log('Data: ', response.body)

            setPhoto(image)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message)
        }
    }
    console.log('Photo: ', photo)
```

Below is the std out of the response.data, this is the data in image_uploads.files, the goal will be to display all the images in image_uploads.files. However, I am taking just the first image filename (ie 2157d425c51a5f3f5a7cf8579137eeb6.jpg) to test and calling setPhoto to set photo state to it. But when I assign it to an image tag the display is blank in the app, I suspect the file name should be attached with something maybe the url to database not sure please help.

The second problem is for every image in image_uploads.files, I want to retrieve its associated data in the post collection which were uploaded along with the image using multipart form data. The post.mediaData.id in post collection is a foreign key which is the image id, but the response.body or response does not have the data in post collection please help. Thanks in advance

```
Object {
  "files": Array [
    Object {
      "_id": "5de29f8dd0f99e6d6a0371ef",
      "chunkSize": 261120,
      "contentType": "image/jpeg",
      "filename": "2157d425c51a5f3f5a7cf8579137eeb6.jpg",
      "isImage": true,
      "length": 1046594,
      "md5": "7e1cb512a36b901e3acfcb9d08f0778f",
      "uploadDate": "2019-11-30T16:57:52.372Z",
    },
    Object {
      "_id": "5de2c1bed0f99e6d6a0371f6",
      "chunkSize": 261120,
      "contentType": "image/jpeg",
      "filename": "3ffe7616d7956084219cb4f134c89798.jpg",
      "isImage": true,
      "length": 1046594,
      "md5": "7e1cb512a36b901e3acfcb9d08f0778f",
      "uploadDate": "2019-11-30T19:23:45.053Z",
    },
  ],
}

Image:  2157d425c51a5f3f5a7cf8579137eeb6.jpg
Data:  undefined
Photo:  2157d425c51a5f3f5a7cf8579137eeb6.jpg
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem ?